# Why does MVC 4 Web API match action parameters from a GET request body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I have a API method that returns a user object by specifying a user id in a request url the restful way, like this:

http://www.myapi.com/users/1

My route looks like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "GetUserByUserId",
            "users/{id}",
            defaults: new { Controller = "User", Action = "GetUserByUserId" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) 
});
```

The controller is named UserController and the method is named GetUserByUserId, and looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public User GetUserByUserId(int id)
{
... returns a User object ....
}
```

If I call the method it responds with the user object, as expected. The id "1" in the url is automatically matched as the GetUserByUserId attribute "id" by the route.

But(!!), if I accidently also provide a JSON serialized object of any kind in the request body, like this:

```
{"Id":6,"PermissionId":0,"UserId":3}
```

MVC is automatically mapping the "Id" property in the request body object to my "id" attribute of the GetUserByUserId method, ignoring the "1" id in my url!

To me, this looks very strange. I know Web API automatically maps the request url and the request body to appropriate attributes in the routed method, but the "Id" in the request body in my example is NOT a simple stand-alone integer, it is a property in a complex type and should not be interpretated as the method attribute "id".

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: How are you providing the JSON serialized object in the request body if you are doing a GET?  I could see how that would be possible if you were doing a POST or a PUT, but the route you have specified is for http GET only, no?  So why, or should I say "how", would you be accidentally providing an object in the request?

Comment: The HTTP/1.1 standard does not explicitly forbid sending a message body when doing a GET request. However a server should never try to parse a request body for a GET request, because it does not have a semantic meaning for the GET request. So in my opinion the MVC Web API parses the GET message incorrectly, or are there other reasons why this is done?

Answer (score 3):

asp.net mvc uses ValueProviderFactories to extract values from request for model binding. You can see configured providers by inspecting [ValueProviderFactories.Factories Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.valueproviderfactories.factories.aspx). With default configuration, this collection consists of

1. ChildActionValueProviderFactory
2. FormValueProviderFactory
3. JsonValueProviderFactory
4. RouteDataValueProviderFactory
5. QueryStringValueProviderFactory
6. HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory

This collection is sorted, and as `JsonValueProviderFactory` appears higher in list, it is used as value provider for `id`, rather than `RouteDataValueProviderFactory`.